# graph databases for store nested comments

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, hierarchical-data, amazon-neptune

I'm designing a data model for a nested comment system. like Reddit.

I read so many blogs throughout the internet, all the solution I found is trying to build a hierarchical data structure in relational databases using designs like Adjacency list, Path enumeration,  Closure table or Nested Sets. along with the different pros and cons, all of these are felt hacky solutions because of the lack of SQL support. MongoDB seems another good NoSQL solution with 100 nested levels and 16MB size limitation.

the solution which I'm seeking for needs to be fast at reading(50 RPS). slow insert and delete are ok. I'm expecting to filter and sort comments by ranking.

Can I use a graph database like neo4j, AWS Neptune for this requirement? will it suitable or over-engineering?

Comment: Nested comments is just a tree, and trees are a particular graph data model, so yes can do it with a graph database(models are the same). For the rest of your question, it's too opened and really subjective ...